# Авторизация Vk, вывод списка друзей?

Tags: python, django, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, python-3.6

Сделал авторизацию Vk с помощью django allauth, пока что возможно просто нажать на авторизацию он зайдет, но не отобразит результат
Как после авторизации увидеть отображение имя авторизованного пользователя и 5 любых друзей пользователя. Так же, чтобы при перезаходах на сайт авторизация не слетала.
Может какие примеры подскажите.

Comment: Приведите свой код